# How did the prophet muhammad (pbsl) remain chaste before Islam?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sex

I want to know how the prophet(pbsl) remain chaste before Islam was revealed. He was 25 years old when he married. Considering that sexual desires starts occuring at around 14-15. Considering that he was good-looking therefore would probably get stares or indirect invitations from women (a.k.a women trying to seduce him). Considering he lived in the age of ignorance. Even if the shaytan companion (Qarin) was removed from him when he was young this does not eliminate his natural sex drive.

Would like to know if they are any authentic hadiths about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

When Allah's (ﷻ) protection upon an in individual is involved, as it was with all Prophets and especially Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ), then there is no factor in the world that can lead that individual astray, be it a fierce enemy or human emotions/desires. Allah (ﷻ) is the Greatest and nothing overcomes His Will/Plan.

- The Protection of Allah (ﷻ) upon the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) started with purifying the Prophet's (ﷺ) heart during childhood ([authentic hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:162c)) so that he (ﷺ) ***naturally inclined*** to what was good/righteous.
- The Protection also included Allah (ﷻ) keeping him (ﷺ) away from places/situations involving evil. Example- while people were in the city worshiping idols, he (ﷺ) was in a Cave meditating. At 14, he (ﷺ) wasn't just hanging around; he (ﷺ) was assisting in battles occurring around him (ﷺ) (e.g., Al Fijr).

Note: You will need to provide solid evidence that he (ﷺ) was ever in a situation where someone tried to seduce him (ﷺ); without evidence, you cannot assume. Moreover, to know how Allah's (ﷻ) protected individual would respond to such a situation, read the Qur'an story on Prophet Yusuf عليه السلام.

It's easy to overcome natural desires with patience, BTW.. even for people today.